# How to implement dynamic buttons html using insertAdjacentHTML JS Method?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm creating a Chrome extension to download videos from a certain site, I need to show the available resolutions buttons in an insertAdjacentHTML, but I don't know how to implement it.

my code:

```
const list = ['240p', '480p', '720p', '1080p']
const container = document.querySelector('.video-info-container');
container.insertAdjacentHTML('beforebegin',`
  <ul class="mlext-container">
    <li>AVALIABLE RESOLUTIONS: <span> <div id="container"></div> </span></li>
  </ul>`)
```

In this case, the buttons should be added to the `<div id="container"></div>` from the code above

I have this code above that creates the buttons in the index.html file inside the body tag if `<div id="container"></div>` is there,but I want to create them inside the  code that was inserted by the insertAjacentHTML method

```
list.forEach(element => {
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
        var button = document.createElement('button');
        button.type = 'button';
        button.innerHTML = element;
        button.className = 'btn-styled';
        button.id = element

        button.onclick = function () {

            if (button.id == '240p') {
                var linkRequest = 
                console.log(element)
            }
            if (button.id == '480p') {
                console.log(element)
            }
            if (button.id == '720p') {
                console.log(element)
            }
            if (button.id == '1080p') {
                console.log(element)
            }

        };

        var container = document.getElementById('container');
        container.appendChild(button);
    }, false);
});
```

how to do it?

Comment: *but I want to create them inside the code that was inserted by the insertAjacentHTML method* - a `<script>` tag is HTML.

Comment: <li><span><div> is not valid HTML - what is the point of having the span and div at all?

Comment: To be able to style my buttons

Comment: You can style a button in an LI

Comment: after doing many tests i got it thanks